# How does fun.call work when the value of thisArg provided for the call to fun is a Function.prototype object?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, prototype, mixins

Below are two ways of defining methods on objects created with the `new` keyword. I'm attempting to compare the workings and effects of each.

1) A functional mixin `asCircle` is defined. Then `.call` injects the mixin into `Circle.prototype` by delegation. The effect is that the `new Circle` instances now have methods such as `.area` mixed in.

```js
    var asCircle = function() {
      this.area = function() {
        return Math.PI * this.radius * this.radius;
      };
      this.grow = function() {
        this.radius++;
      };
      this.shrink = function() {
        this.radius--;
      };
      return this;
    };
     
    var Circle = function(radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    };
    asCircle.call(Circle.prototype);
    var circle1 = new Circle(5);
    var circle2 = new Circle(6);

    console.log(circle1.area());
```

2) A `Circle` function is defined as a constructor with a `radius` property. Functions are then assigned to `Circle.prototype` properties. Effectively any `new Circle` instances can now call these methods e.g `.area()`.

```js
   var Circle = function(radius) {
     this.radius = radius;
   };
   Circle.prototype.area = function() {
     return Math.PI * this.radius * this.radius;
   };
   Circle.prototype.grow = function() {
     this.radius++;
   };
   Circle.prototype.shrink = function() {
     this.radius--;
   };

   var circle1 = new Circle(5);
   var circle2 = new Circle(6);

   console.log(circle1.area());
```

Upon seeing implementation 1 I was taken aback seeing that `.area` could be reused on any new Circle simply by calling the `asCircle` function with `Circle.prototype` as **thisArg**.

Why is the effect of using `.call` in implementation 1 the same as defining these methods **directly** on `Circle.prototype` as in implementation 2?

Answer (score 1):

In the first code snippet

1 .'Call' changes the context of 'this'. When you are calling asCircle.call(Circle.prototype), asCircle is being called with 'this' being   **Circle.prototype**

2.All the methods area/grow and shrink are being added to the prototype which has the same effect as your second code snippet

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

> Why is the effect of using .call in implementation 1 the same as defining these methods directly on Circle.prototype as in implementation 2?

`Function.prototype.call` allows you to set the value of `this` to the first argument.

`asCircle.call(Circle.prototype)` will set the `this` in `asCircle` to `Circle.prototype`.

```
// so now when you see ...
this.area = function() {
  return Math.PI * this.radius * this.radius;
};

// it's the same as ...
Circle.prototype.area = function() {
  return Math.PI * this.radius * this.radius;
}
```

But the `this` inside the `area` function is a different `this` because it's inside a new function. The value of that `this` is determined when that function is called: For example, `circle1.area();` sets the value of `this` in `area` to `circle1`

```
// so now when you see ...
return Math.PI * this.radius * this.radius;

// it's the same as ...
return Math.PI * circle1.radius * circle1.radius
```

---

**Remarks**

And now you've learned how to write code that you should never use. Here's a sensible implementation of `Circle` using two techniques

ES6 class (this is essentially the same thing as your Method 2)

```
class Circle {
  constructor(radius) {
    this.radius = radius
  }
  area () {
    return Math.PI * this.radius * this.radius
  }
  grow () {
    this.radius++
  }
  shrink () {
    this.radius--
  }
}
```

Or a functional way using data abstraction. Note the absence of `this` and how much easier your life is because of it.

```
const makeCircle = r => ({radius: r})
const circleRadius = c => c.radius
const circleArea = c => Math.PI * circleRadius(c) * circleRadius(c)
const circleGrow = c => makeCircle(circleRadius(c) + 1)
const circleShrink = c => makeCircle(circleRadius(c) - 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering the following objects :

```
o = {};
f = function () {
  this.s = "hello";
};
```

`f.call(o)` means `call f with this = o`. Thus, `f.call(o)` is exactly the same as `o.s = "hello"`. The effect of both implementations is the same because `this` and `o` are the same, it's as simple as that :-P

The actual question is, what is the magic behind prototypal inheritance ? In simple words, why a function that belongs to the prototype of Circle is callable from an instance of Circle ?

This is because JavaScript (actually any object oriented language that provides inheritance at runtime) implements what's called a *lookup* mechanism. When a method is not found into an object, JavaScript will keep searching into the prototype of this object, then into the prototype of its prototype, and so on, until the end of the chain.

```
// Person is the parent class of President
Person = function (name) { this.name = name; };
Person.prototype.iam = function () { return this.name; };

// President is a subclass of Person
President = function () { Person.apply(this, arguments); };
President.prototype = new Person();

// trump is an instance of President and Person
trump = new President("Donald");
trump.iam(); // "Donald" (ok)
trump.hasOwnProperty("iam"); // false (wtf!)
President.prototype.hasOwnProperty("iam"); // false (WTF!!)
Person.prototype.hasOwnProperty("iam"); // true (finally...)
```

Bonus (Object is the parent class of everything) :

```
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty("hasOwnProperty"); // true
```